# Tensorflow 2.11.0 on Mac crashes when setting the seed for generating random tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn tensorflow. I installed tf on my Mac (M1 Chip) running 13.2.1.

I created a conda env with tensorflow.

I am trying to generate random tensors by setting the seed and my kernel crashes. Here is the output when I tried to do this.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is some issue with TensorFlow 2.11 in Mac OS as I am also getting the same error. The above mentioned code does not show any error in Google Colab (with PY 3.10, TF 2.11). Please check the replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/970a435cd6a9b96c7ff3a313cd7ce821/76161237.ipynb) for the same.

Please try again by changing the **TensorFlow version to 2.10** in Mac OS which does not show any error.

(Please check the replicated code screenshot as below:)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be resolved in the latest TensorFlow 2.13 version on M1 .

You can direct install 2.13rc0 using below pip command.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.13rc0
```

Here is the output I received from the test.

[Test Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXG6z.png)